# Remove element from node.js Buffer

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have a node.js buffer declared in this way;

```
var buffer_bin;
buffer_bin = new Buffer("ABCDEF", "hex");
```

Contents of `buffer_bin` is "ab cd ef" in binary bytes.

I want to remove the first byte `ab` from `buffer_bin` such that the contents of `buffer_bin` becomes "cd ef".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the slice method in Buffer object.

```
 var new_buffer_bin = buffer_bin.slice(1);
```

Comment: this is wrong it will give `"ab"` instead of `"cd ef"`  need `splice` instead of `slice` and splice doesn't exist :(

Comment: `var new_buffer_bin = buffer_bin.slice(1);` give "cd ef"
but `var new_buffer_bin = buffer_bin.slice(0, 1);` give "ab"
you can combine it with Buffer concat to reimplement splice @SSpoke

Comment: Note that [buffer.slice() is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufslicestart-end) in favour of [buffer.subarray()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufsubarraystart-end)